# How to solve numerically a matrix equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, resolve

I am on python, and i want to solve this equation `M(x,y) + x**2 = 0`, `M(x,y)` is a matrix whose values i know, however i don't know its dependency on `x` nor `y`, for exemple i have these values:

```
M = ([[11,12,13],
     [21,22,23],
     [31,32,33]])
```

I have 2 arrays,

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,3)
y = np.linspace(0,1,3)
```

An i know one thing, that each element of the matrix depends on both `x` and `y`, `M[i][j]=f(x[i],y[j])`.

My question is: How can i solve this equation numerically for y?, i want a contour, or a graph at the end.

I might have not explain the problem really well, so if you have any questions just tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `f` exactly?

Comment: that is the thing, i don't know. I only have the values.

Comment: You say you want to solve for `y`, but you also say that you already have `y = np.linspace(0,1,3)`. Is `y` a constant or an unknown variable?

Comment: One more question: in `x**2`, what is the `**2` operation? Element-wise squaring or the outer product?

Comment: Yes `**2` is the square, ie `x*x`.
In the problem `y` is a variable, but also an unknown. The other thing that is unknown is `f(x,y)`. 
I know that when plotting `y(x)' i have to get something resembling a square root or a log, but slightly different.
I now see that in my code `y` and `x` are not related, but either way i don't know how they are related.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a matrix `M(x, y)` that you assume defines a (continuous?) function `f(x, y)` by giving the outputs for a select number of inputs. Now you want to solve `f(x, y) + x**2 = 0` for `x` and `y` that make this equation true. Is that correct? Does the `x` in `x**2` take on the same value as `x` in `M(x, y)`? I suggest you check out our sister site [math.se] where you can get some answers about the mathematics behind this question.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, and yes the `x` in `M(x,y)` and the `x` in `x**2` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to change the M values because there is no solution with the matrix you gave :

```
import numpy as np
M = np.linspace(-2.,5.,9).reshape(3,3)
x = np.linspace(0,1,3)
y = np.linspace(0,1,3)
```

Then you just have to add x**2 to each value of the M matrix by adding the following X2 matrix :

```
X2 = x*x*np.ones(M.shape)
```

You can display the solutions as a contour with matplolib. Here I choose to display all the values between -0.1 and +0.1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cs = plt.contourf(X2+M, levels=[-0.1,0.1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the levels -0.1 and 0.1 are to show those close to 0 and therefor the solution right?

Comment: Yes, matplotlib.contourf needs at least 2 levels. The green zone contains the solutions. Of course it's an interpolation, given the matrix itself is to small to contains exact solutions.